# Am I correct to get negative cross_val_score when I am using neg_log_loss in scikit-learn 0.18?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, scikit-learn, log-loss

I am working on a data set to predict if someone is going to donate blood from UCI Data repository

The criteria of judging the solution is log loss

So I implement the cross_val_score function from scikit-learn 0.18.1 to evaluate various models with following

```
for clf in classifiers:
    print clf
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, x, y, cv=10, scoring='neg_log_loss')
    print str(np.mean(scores)) + ' +/- ' + str(np.std(scores))
    print
```

And it returns a list of negative number instead of positive number as what suggested in scikit-learn 0.18.1's [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html)

Supposedly, larger the log loss (+ve), the better the classifier should be.  So, a more negative the value, the better the classifier if the cross-value scorer is neg log loss.

However, when I used 'accuracy' as scorer, that paints a different picture

A. Negative Log-loss as Scorer:

```
 LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
      intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
      penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
      verbose=0, warm_start=False)
 -0.5161469532 +/- 0.129596554988

 LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=None, priors=None, shrinkage=None,
          solver='svd', store_covariance=False, tol=0.0001)
 -0.50834388826 +/- 0.0919312491045

 SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
 -0.546319209105 +/- 0.0432643945398

 AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
      learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None)
-0.682692001196 +/- 0.0121743584618

 GaussianProcessClassifier(copy_X_train=True, kernel=None,
         max_iter_predict=100, multi_class='one_vs_rest', n_jobs=1,
         n_restarts_optimizer=0, optimizer='fmin_l_bfgs_b',
         random_state=None, warm_start=False)
 -0.577387181668 +/- 0.0503503242747

 GaussianNB(priors=None)
 -0.722835055005 +/- 0.358807085043

  MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
  -1.06431056541 +/- 0.793644014439
```

B. Accuracy as Scorer:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
      intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
      penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
      verbose=0, warm_start=False)
0.758866995074 +/- 0.035307690622

LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=None, priors=None, shrinkage=None,
          solver='svd', store_covariance=False, tol=0.0001)
0.762315270936 +/- 0.0296027964887

SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear', max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
0.762192118227 +/- 0.00583385186322

AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
      learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None)
0.736514778325 +/- 0.127413500874

GaussianProcessClassifier(copy_X_train=True, kernel=None,
         max_iter_predict=100, multi_class='one_vs_rest', n_jobs=1,
         n_restarts_optimizer=0, optimizer='fmin_l_bfgs_b',
         random_state=None, warm_start=False)
0.738238916256 +/- 0.0812660691629

GaussianNB(priors=None)
0.741625615764 +/- 0.0423107976325

MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
0.709174876847 +/- 0.117722669473
```

That's where I am puzzled because both should give evaluate the merit of the classifier in a consistent direction when you make correct prediction to both classes (i.e. Donate=1, Do not Donate=0).  Apparently, it's not here.  So I wonder if I read incorrectly about the result of the neg_log_loss scorer at the cross_val_score step.

Note:

I then run the whole data set through the combination of train_test_split and metric.log_loss to do the cross validation instead of using the built-in cross_val_score.  I got different result

```
for clf in classifiers:
    log_loss_score[clf]=[]
    for i in range(200):
        x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
        x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
        x_test_scaled = scaler.transform(x_test)
        clf.fit(x_train_scaled,y_train)
        y_train_pred = clf.predict(x_train_scaled)
        y_test_pred = clf.predict(x_test_scaled)
        log_loss_score[clf].append([log_loss(y_train,y_train_pred),log_loss(y_test,y_test_pred)])
    print clf
    print
    print "Log loss on train set: %.4f" %np.mean(log_loss_score[clf][0]),"+/-",np.std(log_loss_score[clf][0])
    print "Log loss on test set: %.4f" %np.mean(log_loss_score[clf][1]),"+/-",np.std(log_loss_score[clf][1])
    print
```

Then it returns something that contradicts cross_val_score using 'neg_log_loss' as scoring method:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Log loss on train set: 7.7932 +/- 0.605878887483
Log loss on test set: 8.1920 +/- 0.392851665879

LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=None, priors=None, shrinkage=None,
              solver='svd', store_covariance=False, tol=0.0001)

Log loss on train set: 8.3341 +/- 1.04925108223
Log loss on test set: 8.0634 +/- 0.521409562813

SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

Log loss on train set: 8.3064 +/- 0.0787685630429
Log loss on test set: 8.4773 +/- 0.50679396222

AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
          learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None)

Log loss on train set: 7.0783 +/- 0.907583906119
Log loss on test set: 7.1640 +/- 0.821879069667

GaussianProcessClassifier(copy_X_train=True, kernel=None,
             max_iter_predict=100, multi_class='one_vs_rest', n_jobs=1,
             n_restarts_optimizer=0, optimizer='fmin_l_bfgs_b',
             random_state=None, warm_start=False)

Log loss on train set: 6.8217 +/- 0.565253749692
Log loss on test set: 7.0924 +/- 1.09311772514

GaussianNB(priors=None)

Log loss on train set: 8.9628 +/- 0.220948915653
Log loss on test set: 8.5923 +/- 0.406722916715
```

Scikit learn documentation said the 'neg_log_loss' is exactly same as the metric.log_loss. Apparently, it's is not the case with this data set.  That's where I got lost.

Comment: You may need to explain a little bit further, what's the problem and what the code is doing.

Comment: Your title question seems potentially valid here, but the body is nothing but Python code, which many people don't read. Can you add some text to clarify your situation, & sufficient pseudo-code to be intelligible?

Comment: Sorry.  I am using log loss function to decide on the performance of various classifieds.  According to the scikit learn documentation, I am supposed to get a positive log loss value and smaller the better.  However, I get all these negative scores which is rather abnormal. So, I have problem to interpret the result. Whether I should say the multinominal classifier is the best.  However, when I use accuracy as the loss function, Linear  discriminating should give the best accuracy instead. So I am a bit lost on whether the built-in log loss function of scikit learn has changed the setting.

Comment: It might be better to edit your comment into the text of the question and say a bit more about what your data-set looks like. Giving a table of the values which you were not expecting and the circumstances under which they arose might also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think the misunderstanding turns on this statement.

> Supposedly, larger the log loss (+ve), the better the classifier should be. So, a more negative the value, the better the classifier if the cross-value scorer is neg log loss.

A *more negative* value is *farther* from zero and has negative sign, so it is **smaller**.

A **larger** negative value is *closer to zero*.

For example, the following is true: $-100 < -10 < -1 < 0$.

With this understanding in hand, the LDA model has both the largest negative log-loss and the largest accuracy.

Comment: However, when I combine train_test_split with metric.log_loss, i get the result that GaussianNB gives the best performance instead.

Comment: These statistics, like all statistics, are random variables. Changing the data that you use to measure them will change the statistic. You changed the data when you switched from cross-validation to train/test split.

Comment: I understand it's random variable like and that's why I added std to see how varied it is.  That's what I want. The thing i don't understand is why the neg log loss under cross val is so different from the values generated by log loss.

Comment: **because you've changed the data**

Comment: Yes, I understand the data sets are different under two scenarios.  What I don't understand is why cross val used in conjunction with neg log loss would give value like -0.56 while train test split with log loss metric would give 8.90.  They are so different in terms of magnitude and sign.  So I want to find out if the for,USA behind these two metrics are somewhat different.

Comment: Negative log loss is the negative of the log loss, so that explains the change in sign. The magnitude is probably the difference between taking the mean and average for each sample. To verify, retrieve the predicted values and do the computation.